# Adapting an empty struct for Boost Fusion

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I have an empty struct:

```
struct MyStruct {};
```

I want to adapt this to be used by Boost Fusion. Ordinarily I would use `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`, but this macro requires two parameters to name the struct and list its fields. Is there anyway to tell the macro that the fields are non-existent?

Motivation: I am using Boost Spirit to define a parser. The struct is for a `boost::variant` that is then passed to `boost::apply_visitor()`. Some of the other items in the variant given the `boost::fusion::for_each()` treatment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried passing `/**/` as the second parameter and it compiled for me (g++-4.6.2).

```
    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, /**/);
```

Comment: Visual C++ v140 does refuses to eat it though.

Comment: @LoftyLion Unfortunately I don't have MSVC to test this, you may have better luck asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `BOOST_PP_EMPTY`. No guarantees that it will work, but given the implementation it seems likely.

Comment: I'm getting an error `'BOOST_PP_IIF_0' does not name a type`. Thanks for the suggestion anyway though.